# Blowfish on android studio for encryption/decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption, blowfish

I've searched almost all topics here about this subject but I still can't figure out what's wrong. I've created 3 `EditText` on my android app:
`EditText` where you insert the key/password to encrypt and decrypt;
`EditText2` where it is shown the encrypted text; 
`EditText3` where it is shown the decrypted text.

Since it's still an early test, I've put the message or string to Crypt as variable in the app.

The Problem is that the encryption give something like a blowfish algorithm, so no problem there (it end with 2 == so I think it's working right). I've also tried to decode the string before the decryption or using the raw `byte[]` from encryption without any good result. The decryption doesn't give back the original String text, instead give something bigger than the encrypted text. I don't have a preference on the mode of blowfish so I started easy as Blowfish/CFB/NoPadding.

`str_key`, `str2` and `str3` are declared public for now. `str2` will set the text for `EditText2` field and `str3` will set the text for `EditText3` field.
An example of output:
[Example of output generated from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXA32.jpg)

Here's the code :

```
public void encrypt(){
    //encrypt
    EditText mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    str_key = (String) mEdit.getText().toString();

    int iterationCount = 1000;
    int keyLength = 256;
    int saltLength = keyLength / 8; 

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(str_key.toCharArray(), salt,
            iterationCount, keyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
    try {
        keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "Blowfish");

    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( cipher == null || key == null) {
        //throw new Exception("Invalid key or cypher");
        str2="error";
    }
    else {
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,ivParams);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            raw = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        str2 = Base64.encodeToString(raw,Base64.DEFAULT);

    }


}
```

Here is the decrypt function:

```
    public void decrypt(){
          int iterationCount = 1000;
          int keyLength = 256;
          int saltLength = keyLength / 8; 
          SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
          byte[] salt = new byte[saltLength];
          random.nextBytes(salt);
          KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(str_key.toCharArray(), salt,  iterationCount, keyLength);
          SecretKeyFactory  keyFactory = null;
          try {
               keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
              } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
              byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
              try {
                keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
                } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "Blowfish");



    Cipher cipher2 = null;
    try {
        cipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    iv = new byte[cipher2.getBlockSize()];
    random.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    try {
        cipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec );
    } catch (InvalidKeyException  | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] app= Base64.decode(str2,Base64.DEFAULT);

    try {
        decryptedBytes = cipher2.doFinal(app);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    str3 = Base64.encodeToString(decryptedBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You encode the encrypted result to base64 but then when you decrypt, you take the plain bytes of that base64.  You should instead base64 decode first to get the actual byte array of ciphertext and then decrypt that.

You are also deriving your key directly from the UTF8 byte array, which is a very poor way to do so.  You should instead use a KDF.  PBKDF2 is the most commonly used here.

The way you generate an IV (by not generating one at all) is very poor also.  It should be randomly generated and prepended to the ciphertext.  It doesn't need to be secret, just unpredictable.

Lastly, you don't use a HMAC at all, so anyone could change the ciphertext and you wouldn't know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've also tried to use the base64 decode and also, use the original "pre" encoded byte array for the decryption without result. Can you make an example of what I should do ?
Should I just change UTF-8 with KDF.PBKDF2 ? 
I've also tried generating the IV as : IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(keySpec.getEncoded()); //in the decrypting function;
but I get runtime error. Can you give me an example for this too ?

Comment: How can I use HMAC to avoid changing the cipherText?

Comment: This is all stuff you can google search, you won't learn anything if I just write the code for you!  If you tried it even with decoding the base64 then you simply just did something wrong.  Try editing the code in your original post to what you tried and I'll help you from there.

Comment: I wasn't looking for an easy way out. I'll look into the stuffs you mentioned and as always I thank you for your answer. I just got frustrated since I've been searching here and on google for the past 22 days getting only code much simpler than the one I had to use for android studio and almost none had to specifically use the IV parameters claiming their code "worked". I've also added the decoded test I used in the decrypt function and as a result I get a different Blowfish encrypted code.

Comment: I've also added the PBKDF2 key deriving which also help generate the IV parameters for encryption. Changed the instance to Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding. Is it better now ? I'll try to change the decryption too and see what happens.

Comment: The IV needs to random and unpredictable.  PBKDF2 is predictable.  You should just randomly generate the IV and prepend it.

Comment: Ok, I'll test this solution too. Have you seen the decrypt function with the decoded Base64 part ? The output of that is still erratic.

Comment: Probably because you aren't using PBKDF2 in your decrypt like you are in your encrypt.

Comment: I've updated the decrypt function with the PBKDF2. Now I get a runtime error: "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted"  which I think it referes to the "decryptedBytes = cipher2.doFinal(app);" part.

Comment: If you need to encrypt data it might be better to just use a library that has already been written, rather than using AES directly.  No offence, but any solution you come up with that "works" is likely to be insecure.

Comment: Ok, I don't plan on making the safest app out there but I'll try. Do you have any suggestions for a library to use ?